# Sum and difference of permutations equal to a square number

Tags: combinatorics

How many examples are there of the permutations of any 3 numbers whose sum and difference is a square number or perfect square ,  say you have  three numbers  a ,b, c    ,  treat  the permutation  say  391   as  an integer. and  another permutation of those numbers  say  931  . Using any three numbers  determine  when
the sums and difference of these permutations  is a perfect square  such as  (391+931)= a square  and  931-391=  a square  but these particular numbers do not result in two  squares.

Answer (score 1):

$872 + 728 = 1600 = 40^2$ and $872 - 728 = 144 = 12^2$

I found this pair using a small computer program.
First I made a list of squares up to 2000 (roughly the maximum sum of two three digit numbers).
Then for each square $n = a^2$ we try every possible decomposition $n = i + (n - i)$, we want $i - (n - i)$ to be a square also.
Whenever we find such a pair with $a + b$ and $a - b$ both a square we display it on the screen.
Then I simply looked through the list by hand (it wasn't that big), and found the above pair.
You could also then automatically check for pairs whose digits are permutations of each other and count them up if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am sure there are many more  examples of this relationship using other numbers.  What about trying it with the permutations of 4 numbers  or  5  or 6  or seven  ?

Comment: Alex   Notice  that when you divide  872   and  728   by 8 you get  109  and  91  which are the sides of a primitive right triangle.  109 is the hypotenuse and  91  is  a leg.